# Wait while image is loaded in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following problem.

```
function getBase64Image() {
    var svg = //some svg string;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var mimetype = 'image/png';
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = 600;
    var timg = new Image(),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    timg.width = 600;
    timg.height = 600;
    timg.onload = function () {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            try {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
                ctx.drawImage(timg, 0, 0);
            }
            catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
       var strData = canvas.toDataURL(mimetype);
       document.body.removeChild(canvas);
       img_data = strData;
        }
        timg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + svg;
    }
    return img_data;
}
```

Basically, I want to convert svg to png.
I have svg string, I then load image and draw it with canvas. Then I fetch base64 string for png image.
The problem I encounter is that function getBase64Image exits before image is loaded.
How can I prevent it?

Maybe use deferred or rewrite function?
I Googled, but couldn't find close answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change an asynchronous function in a synchronous one.

The simplest solution is to pass a callback :

```
function fetchBase64Image(callback) {
    var svg = //some svg string;
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var mimetype = 'image/png';
    canvas.width = 600;
    canvas.height = 600;
    var timg = new Image(),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    timg.width = 600;
    timg.height = 600;
    timg.onload = function () {
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            try {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
                ctx.drawImage(timg, 0, 0);
            }
            catch (e) {
                return false;
            }
       var strData = canvas.toDataURL(mimetype);
       document.body.removeChild(canvas);
       img_data = strData;
       callback(img_data);
      }
      timg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + svg;
    }
}
```

And you use it like this :

```
fetchBase64Image(function(img_data){
   // use the image img_data
}):
```